# why does activerecord none? return false?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model Account that `has_and_belongs_to_many :categories`.

When testing whether a given category is already linked to an account (before creating it), I do this:

```
account = Account.find(1)
account.categories.where(name: "rent").none?
```

This returns `false` (although "rent" is a categorie for an account that already exists).

```
account.categories.where(name: "monkey").none?
```

returns `true`

Why doesn't an existing relation return `true` and an non existing `false`? Or should I use another method for testing this?

Comment: That's what it's supposed to do:
https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/none%3F

Answer (score 1):

You probably want the [`any?`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-any-3F) method since...

```rb
[1,2].none?
=> false

[1,2].any?
=> true
```